# Phonegap on Android emulator doesn't run index.html

Tags: android, cordova, emulation

I am trying to run the sample (or any) application with Phonegap in Android emulator (Motodev Studio 3.0.1). I followed all the instructions in the Phonegap's manual, but instead of the contents of index.html, an ordinary android activity starts. I am using Phonegap version 1.7.0 and Android emulator with target api 8,10,14. In all cases the problem is the same. No errors, but index.html is not loaded. What could be wrong?

Info from console:

```
[2012-06-03 13:43:59 - HelloCordova] Android Launch!
[2012-06-03 13:43:59 - HelloCordova] adb is running normally.
[2012-06-03 13:43:59 - HelloCordova] Performing phonegap.cordova.hello.HelloCordovaActivity activity launch
[2012-06-03 13:44:08 - HelloCordova] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_api_8'
```

Regards

Adi

Answer (score 0):

In your java code you need to extend your class to DroidGap, not Activity. 
You need to load your URL as super.loadUrl(). find the following code....

code:

```
   public class DemoActivity extends DroidGap {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index11.html");

        }
     }
```

Comment: Code is correct ( class HelloCordovaActivity extends DroidGap ), but problem is the same. Hmm... Maybe this is not problem with code, only with emulator config ?

Comment: I solved problem. Problem was with AVD settings not with phonegap. Thanks and regards